# getElementById on page with multiple instances of same component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm writing a small vue app. On one page, I include multiple instances of the same component like so

```
<my-component v-for="t in todos"></my-component>
```

Within that component, I display data like the name and description of the to-do and the date it is due. I check if it is overdue with this function

```
let d = new Date();
let overdue = false;
this.deadline = new Date(this.deadline);
if (this.deadline < d) { overdue = true; }
if (overdue && !this.completed) {
    document.getElementById('taskCard').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

This correctly detects when a task is overdue, but it always makes the first to-do red instead of the overdue one. How can I target the component correctly? My thought is that when I do document.getElementById, it finds the first #taskCard because it's looking on the page. Is there anyway to do something like this.getElementById or my-component.getElementById?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you share the code of `my-component`?

Comment: IDs should be unique across the whole HTML page. `getElementById` should never be able to point at more than one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't the "Vue" way of doing things.

Instead what you want to do is let the data drive your display, so instead of trying to find all overdue things and style them, have the things style themselves if they are over due.

For example

```
<my-component :style='compstyle' v-for="t in todos"></my-component>
```

Then on your component have a property to bind that style

```
computed: {
    compstyle : function(){
        return (new Date(this.deadline) < new Date()) ? {'backgroundColor' : 'red'} : {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That was super helpful and a very clean way to do this. I'm new to vue, so it's great seeing your thought process. Thanks!